# Perl Module Creation & Usage - Undefined subroutine

Tags: perl, module, exporter

I am trying to create & use modules in a new script I'm doing but I'm not familiar with modules yet.
I've been following some tutorials, and even if I have the "almost" exact same code as in the tutorial, it doesn't work and when I run my test-script I get the following error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::func1 called at ../../bin/fftg.pl line 21.
```

Here is my main script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# ......
# comments here
# ......
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename qw(dirname);
use Cwd  qw(abs_path);
use lib dirname(dirname abs_path $0) . '/lib';

use FFTG::PID qw(:DEFAULT);

print func1(10,20);
```

and here is the module, created as file **lib/FFTG/PID.pm** :

```
package PID;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;

our $VERSION     = 1.00;
our @ISA         = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT      = qw(&func1 &func2);       # I tried all lines without &
our @EXPORT_OK   = qw(&func1 &func2);       # I tried all lines without &
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( DEFAULT => [qw(&func1)],
                     Both    => [qw(&func1 &func2)]);


sub func1
{
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    return $x + $y;

}

sub func2
{
    return "tata\n";
}

1;
```

what am I doing wrong please ?
I tried to load the thing using :

```
use FFTG::PID qw(:DEFAULT);
use FFTG::PID;
use FFTG::PID qw(funct1);
use FFTG::PID qw(&funct1);
```

nothing works (same error)

I also tried to modify the module, modifying these lines removing or adding the & :

```
our @EXPORT      = qw(func1 func2);
our @EXPORT_OK   = qw(func1 func2);
```

same problem

any hints ?

my folders & files are :

```
MIF/root@sm1p0003vmo /wminfs/mc/projects/FFTGv2: pwd
/wminfs/mc/projects/FFTGv2
MIF/root@sm1p0003vmo /wminfs/mc/projects/FFTGv2: ls -al bin/fftg.pl
-rwxr-x---   1 root     root         545 May 18 09:49 bin/fftg.pl
MIF/root@sm1p0003vmo /wminfs/mc/projects/FFTGv2: ls -al lib/FFTG/PID.pm
-rw-r-----   1 root     root         344 May 18 09:37 lib/FFTG/PID.pm
MIF/root@sm1p0003vmo /wminfs/mc/projects/FFTGv2:
```

thanks 
regards,

Comment: (1) a typo: you call the second function `func1` as well.  It seems that you mean `func2`.  This is the subroutine redefined warning. (2) Drop those `&`, they are wrong. (3) Use only `@EXPORT_OK`

Comment: thanks for your answer, I renamed the second function ! my bad.
where should I rename the & btw ? (in the module ? in which array ?), thanks

Comment: The `&` just should NOT be anywhere there, just remove it. Delete.

Comment: ok I just removed it everywhere, same problem (it didn't change anything) :(

Comment: I added comments to your code snippet

Comment: thanks Patrick, I tried the exact code you mentioned, but I am still having the exact same error  (Undefined subroutine &main::func1 called at ../../bin/fftg.pl line 23)

Comment: Try in your script: use FFTG::PID qw(&func1);   print func1(..); I will edit your code

Comment: same problem.
could it be some kind of "include error" ? (e.g package not found in the directory or other). when I print the contents of @INC, I can see the lib folder (and under that lib folder, I get my FFTG folder, with PID.pm inside). I also get the same error if I forget the "use" before the print..

Comment: same thing :(
 -- Undefined subroutine &FFTG::PID::func1 called at ../../bin/fftg.pl line 25.

Comment: Then try this: go in your folder an run the "pwd" command to show your excat path. Then you also could paste this path to your script like this: use lib 'your hole path/lib'. Please tell me your hole path

Comment: yes that's what I tried a minute ago, I tried to include both the whole path, and the FFTG folder as well using two "use lib", example : use lib '/wminfs/mc/projects/FFTGv2/lib';
use lib '/wminfs/mc/projects/FFTGv2/lib/FFTG';

Comment: An what script ist "fftg.pl" ? Because in your code snippet is no line 21

Comment: it's the exact same as the first one I posted, with some comments and commented lines as I'm trying many things, I can edit my post and post the Exact version with comments etc.. but it shouldn't change anything I suppose

Comment: it just looks like the "use FFTG::PID <something>" is not taken in consideration, that's odd :(

Comment: okay the only Problem was your package declartion. Use package FFTG::PID; and your code will work. Tahnks also to @zdim

Comment: thanks again both of you, it works now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few errors, and a few things that can be done better.

- The module name [needs to match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433246/4653379) its (relative) location, so: `package FFTG::PID;`
- There can be no `&` when listing subroutines for `EXPORT`s in the module; those should be *names* and the `&` isn't a part of the name.  From [use pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) (my emphasis)

  > Imports some **semantics** into the current package from the named module
- All-caps names are a risky idea as they may be taken, and `DEFAULT` cannot be used here

It is generally a good advice to use `@EXPORT_OK`, and not `@EXPORT`.

Finally, the line that sets up [lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) is asking for trouble.  Use [FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html).

Package **lib/FFTG/PID.pm**

```
package FFTG::PID;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw(import);
our $VERSION     = 1.00;
our @EXPORT_OK   = qw(func1 func2);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 
    default => [ qw(func1) ], 
    both    => [ qw(func1 func2) ]
);

sub func1
{
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    return $x + $y;       
}   

sub func2
{
    return "tata\n";
}   

1;
```

where I've also replaced the explicit setup of `@ISA` with the [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html)'s`import` method.

The main program

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib "$RealBin/lib";

use FFTG::PID qw(:default);

say func1(10,20);
```

It prints a line with `30`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @zdim