# Perl Module Creation - Undefined subroutine

Tags: perl, module, package

I'm new in perl and I'm trying to do this exercise but it doesn't work.

This is my module that I created.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

package Prepare;
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw( clean my_print );

sub clean{
    return chomp($_[0]);
}

sub my_print{
    return print("The Results: $_[0]\n");
}

1;
```

And this my script `test_lib.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use lib '/home/foobar/code';
use My::Prepare;

print "Enter a word: ";
my $input=<STDIN>;

print "You entered: $varia";

clean($input);
my_print($input);
```

I get this error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::clean called at ./test_lib.pl line 13,  line 1.
```

Comment: Your package is called `Prepare`, not `My::Prepare`. Change `use My::Prepare;` to `use Prepare;`

Comment: Questions:  Where is the module's file, in relation to the script (and/or to the path in `use lib`)?  What is the name of that (module's) file?

Comment: `package Prepare;`, `use My::Prepare;`... one of those is wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When it comes to package naming, three things need to agree:

- location and name of the package file
- name in the [package](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) statement in the package file (the namespace)
- the [use](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) statement for the package in the code that uses it

They need to "agree" as follows.

If the package declaration in its file is `package My::Package;` then the package need be used as `use My::Package`, and its file is `Package.pm` in the directory `My`.

This directory `My` itself need be in a location that the interpreter will search, or we need to inform it where to look. Custom packages are usually not in directories that are searched by default, which is what [lib pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) is for:  With your

```
use lib '/home/foobar/code';
```

I'd expect `My` directory, with `Package.pm` in it, to be in `/home/foobar/code` directory.

Then here is your example, with fixed names and with a few more adjustments.

File `/home/foobar/code/My/Prepare.pm` :

```
package My::Prepare;

use warnings;
use strict;

use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( clean my_print );

sub clean { chomp(@_); return @_ }

sub my_print { print "The Results: $_[0]\n" }

1;
```

And a script that uses this module

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use lib '/home/foobar/code';

use My::Prepare qw(clean my_print);

print "Enter a word: ";
my $input = <STDIN>;

print "You entered: $input";

my ($cleaned_input) = clean($input);
my_print($cleaned_input);
```

Please adjust paths above to your actual directory structure, by adding or removing path components as suitable. The name `My::` in particular is sticking out.

A few notes.

- there is no need for the "shebang" line (`#!/usr/bin/perl`) in a module
- use of [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) above is a bit more modern
- I strongly recommend using `@EXPORT_OK` (instead of `@EXPORT`), so that all listed symbols must be specifically imported by the user of the module. That is just better for everybody
- Unrelated to packaging but important: The `clean` sub returns a list, so we need to assign from it *to a list*; assigning to a scalar would end up assigning the number of elements of the list.

  So even with just one variable passed around we need those parenthesis to indicate the list assignment, `my ($cleaned_input) = ...`, so the list of scalars returned from the sub is assigned to the list of variables (in parenthesis) on the left-hand-side, one for one.

  Then, when a list with just one variable is returned it is assigned to the first variable listed in parens, as intended.  Without the parens `$cleaned_input` would be assigned `1`, the length of the returned list in this case.

Comment: My bad. I thought I was editing one of my own answers. Reverted changes.