# Call perl function from another perl script with different Active perl versions

Tags: windows, perl, object, version, activeperl

We have two versions of Active perl 5.6 and 5.24. We have web services which has to be executed on Active perl '5.24' versions(to adopt TLS 1.2 version) and this needs to be invoked from Active perl '5.6' version. We are using windows operating system.

**Steps followed :**
        Caller code which is executed in 5.6 version invokes the 5.24 version using system /require command.

**Problem:**
    How to call the 5.24 perl function(example: webservicecall(arg1){return "xyz") from 5.6 perl script through system command, require or etc..?
    Also how to get the return value of perl function 5.24?

**Note:**
    Its a temporary work around to have two perl versions and the we have a plan to do upgrade it for higher version.

Here perl version 5.6 installed in "C:\Perl\bin\perl\" and perl version 5.24 installed in "D:\Perl\bin\perl\".

```
"**p5_6.pl**"

print "Hello Perl5_6\n";
system('D:\Perl\bin\perl D:\sample_program\p5.24.pl');

print $OUTFILE;
$retval = Mul(25, 10);
print ("Return value is $retval\n" );

"**p5_24.pl**"

print "Hello Perl5_24\n";
our $OUTFILE  = "Hello test";
sub Mul($$)  
{
    my($a, $b ) = @_;  
    my $c = $a * $b;
    return($c);
}
```

I have written sample program for detail information to call perl 5.24 version from perl script 5.6 version. During execution I didn't get the expected output. How to get the "return $c" value & the "our $OUTFILE" value of p5_24.pl in p5_6.pl script?

**Note:** The above is the sample program based on this I will modify the actual program using serialized data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the code for the function that needs v5.24 in a wrapper script, written just so that it runs that function (and prints its result). Actually, I'd recommend writing a module with that function and then loading that module in the wrapper script.

Then run that script under the wanted (5.24) interpreter, by invoking it via its full path.  (You may need to be careful to make sure that all libraries and environment are right.)   Do this in a way that allows you to pick up its output. That can be anything from backticks (`qx`) to pipe-open or, better, to good modules. There is a range of modules for this, like `IPC::System::Simple`, `Capture::Tiny`, `IPC::Run3`, or `IPC::Run`.  Which to use would depend on  how much you need out of that call.

You can't call a function in a running program but to have it somehow run under another program.

Also, variables (like `$OUTFILE`) defined in one program cannot be seen in another one. You can print them from the v5.24 program, along with that function result, and then parse that whole output in the v5.6 program.  Then the two programs would need a little "protocol" -- to either obey an order in which things are printed, or to have prints labeled in some way.

Much better, write a module with functions and variables that need be shared.  Then the v5.24 program can load the module and import the function it needs and run it, while the v5.6 program can load the same module but only to pick up that variable (and also run the v5.24 program).

Here is a sketch of all this.  The package file `SharedBetweenPerls.pm`

```
package SharedBetweenPerls;

use warnings; 
use strict;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(Mul export_vars);

my $OUTFILE = 'test_filename';

sub Mul { return $_[0] * $_[1] }

sub export_vars { return $OUTFILE }

1;
```

and then the v5.24 program (used below as `program_for_5.24.pl`) can do

```
use warnings;
use strict;

# Require this to be run by at least v5.24.0
use v5.24;

# Add path to where the module is, relative to where this script is
# In our demo it's the script's directory ($RealBin)
use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib $RealBin;

use SharedBetweenPerls qw(Mul);
    
my ($v1, $v2) = @ARGV;

print Mul($v1, $v2);
```

while the v5.6 program can do

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib $RealBin;

use SharedBetweenPerls qw(export_vars);

my $outfile = export_vars();  #--> 'test_filename'

# Replace "path-to-perl..."  with an actual path to a perl
my $from_5.24 = qx(path-to-perl-5.24 program_for_5.24.pl 25 10);  #--> 250

say "Got variable: $outfile, and return from function: $from_5.24";
```

where `$outfile` has the string `test_filename` while `$from_5.24` variable is `250`.<sup>†</sup>

This is tested to work as it stands if both programs, and the module, are in the same directory, with names as in this example.  (And with `path-to-perl-5.24` replaced with the actual path to your v5.24 executable.)  If they are at different places you need to adjust paths, probably the package name and the `use lib` line. See [lib pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html).

Please note that there are better ways to run an external program --- see the recommended modules above.  All this is a *crude demo* since many details depend on what exactly you do.

Finally, the programs can also connect via a socket and exchange all they need but that is a bit more complex and may not be needed.

---

<sup>†</sup>  The question's been edited, and we now have `D:\Perl\bin\perl` for `path-to-perl-5.24` and `D:\sample_program\p5.24.pl` for `program_for_5.24`.

Note that with such a location of the `p5.24.pl` program you'd have to come up with a suitable location for the module and then its name would need to have (a part of) that path in it and to be loaded with such name.  See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54433026/perl-module-creation-undefined-subroutine/54433246#54433246).

---

*A crude demo without a module (originally posted)*

As a very crude sketch, in your program that runs under v5.6 you could do

```
my $from_5.24 = qx(path-to-perl-5.24 program_for_5.24.pl 25 10);
```

where the `program_for_5.24.pl` then could be something like

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub Mul { return $_[0] * $_[1] }

my ($v1, $v2) = @ARGV;

print Mul($v1, $v2);
```

and the variable `$from_5.24` ends up being `250` in my test.

Comment: I have shared my queries in detail

Comment: @Grace Your sample `p5.24.pl` program needs to run that function which it defines (`Mul`), and to print what it wants to send to whoever calls it. So you need in it `print Mul(25,10);`.  Then call the `p5.24.pl` program (from the v5.6 program) so that you can get its output (what `system` doesn't do), for example `my $ret = qx(path-to-perl-5.24 D:\sample_program\p.5.24.pl)` .  (And remove that print of `Hello` from `p5.24.pl` program :).  Or, have `p5.24.pl` print its results to a file which the other program can then read, after it invoked `p5.24.pl`.

Comment: @Grace I added a basic example to the end of my answer

Comment: @Grace Edited and added to the answer

Comment: @Grace Added a line of code to help loading the module (to both programs) in case you didn't know how to do that

Comment: 1) use v5.24.2;
Here how to set the 5.24 version which is installed in the path "D:/perl_5.24/bin/"


2) use lib '.';
Here how to set the lib path which is installed in "D:/perl_5.24/lib/"

Comment: # Require this to be run by at least v5.24.2
use v5.24.2; 
I have 5.24.0 is it ok or 5.24.2 is mandatory?

Comment: @Grace  Oh, I goofed it up -- for some reason I thought you said 5.24.2 -- but you didn't!  The question is clear, you say 5.24.  So it's good to say `use v5.24;`. That will be satisfied by `5.24.0` and higher.  Sorry about that, fixed

Comment: @Grace (Otherwise, it won't work: a line `use v5.24.2;` won't allow it to run with `5.24.0`)

Comment: @Grace Didn't notice a comment above with two questions.  (1) For running another Perl version there is (hopefully) no need to set up anything -- just call it with a full path (2) To load a module from that path you need `use lib 'D:/perl_5.24/lib';`.  But please read up on this, for example from the link (or docs) as it may be different depending on details

Comment: For the above question got the answer from You. But I am facing an issue while passing object(which is another scenario) as an input parameter from perl5.6.pl to perl5.24.pl. Provided code which has the problem. Need suggession.

Comment: @Grace I see -- that appears to be a rather different problem.  I suggest to write it up as a new question.

Comment: I have posted as a new question related to this question.  Need suggession. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132795/passing-object-as-an-input-parameter-with-different-perl-versions

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly call a Perl function running with another Perl version. You would need to create a program which explicitly invokes the function. The input and output need to be explicitly serialized in order to be transported between these two programs.

Serializing could be done with `Data::Dumper`, `Storable` or similar. If lower performance is needed you could invoke the program which provides the function with `system` and share the serialized data with temporary files or pipes.  Or you could create some client-server architecture and share the serialized data with sockets. The latter is faster since it skips the repeated start and teardown of the other process but instead keeps it running.

Comment: I have shared my queries in detail