# Use a Perl module which is root directory inside another directory

Tags: perl

We have a Perl framework in which we have created some customized module. Whenever I am trying to use the modules inside a sub-directory it throw Error.

Below is my Folder structure, `frameworkfolder` being the base/root directory of the project:

```
.../frameworkfolder/PerlModules/Initialize.pm
```

I need to use this `Initialize.pm` in a Perl file which is in another directory

```
.../frameworkfolder/TestCases/FVT/fvt/fvt.pl
```

In `fvt.pl`, when I `use PerlModules::Initialize`, it throws the following error:

```
Can't locate PerlModules/Initialize.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PerlModules::Initialize module) (@INC contains: /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.28.1/aix-thread-multi /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.28.1 /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.28.1/aix-thread-multi /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.28.1)
```

How do I use the `Initialize.pm` Perl package from `fvt.pl`? or any other perl files inside any other directory?

I have tried below solutions but no luck:

```
use lib '../../../frameworkfolder';
```

and

```
use FindBin; 
use lib "$FindBin::Bin"
```

and

```
use FindBin;
use File::Spec;
use lib File::Spec->catdir($FindBin::Bin, '../../', 'lib');
```

and

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w -I /frameworkfolder/
```

Did not find answer in : [How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804)

Comment: `use lib '/full/path/to/dir/with/Module';` **has to** work if it's all correct.  You can shorten it (using `FindBin`) but get it working first. Or set up `PERL5LIB` correctly.  Note that the `package` declaration in the module needs to be written, and the module `use`d, accordingly; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433246/4653379). In short: If the module has `package Dir::Mod;` then you need `use Dir::Mod;` and the `use lib '...';` needs to have the path that contains `Dir` (not `Mod.pm`!)

Comment: Please edit the question and post: (1) Exact `package` declaration from the module; (2) Exact `use` statement from programs that use it (3) Exact location of the module on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `PerlModules/Initialize.pm` contains `package Initialize;`:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$FindBin::RealBin/../../../PerlModules";
use Initialize;
```

If `PerlModules/Initialize.pm` contains `package PerlModules::Initialize;`:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$FindBin::RealBin/../../..";
use PerlModules::Initialize;
```

(The former makes a lot more sense.)

Notes:

- `$Bin` breaks if a symlink to the script is used. `$RealBin` avoids this problem.
- No point in using File::Spec. Your module isn't going to be used on VMS or Classic Mac OS.
- I have no idea why you think of the of paths you used (`../../../frameworkfolder`, `../../lib` and `/frameworkfolder/`) would work. None of those are remotely close. Have someone teach you the basics of relative paths.